Sitecore 10.4 Disabling Identity Server breaks site

I followed the instructions for disabling identity server from https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/104/sitecore-experience-manager/understanding-sitecore-authentication-behavior-changes.html#disable-sitecore-identity as I have done for previous sites, but on activating the config, the entire site breaks with this error "Cannot find options for the 'SitecoreIdentityJwtBearer' authentication type."

You will need to set the authentication type as empty for GraphQL, through below configuration, when you disable the identity server in Sitecore.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
  <sitecore role:require="Standalone or ContentManagement">
    <authoring>
      <graphql>
        <tokenValidator>
          <param desc="authenticationType">
            <patch:delete/>
          </param>
          <param desc="authenticationType"></param>
        </tokenValidator>
      </graphql>
    </authoring>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>

Be default, there is a config file located at below location that can be used to set authentication type to empty.
App_Config\Include\Examples\Sitecore.GraphQL.IdentityServer.Disabler.config.example

Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
